# Eclipse EGit push to upstream vs push to branch

Tags: eclipse, git

I am new to Git and GitLab. There is a GitLab (remote server) has many projects and I was asked to download "Foo_Master" branch from Project named "Foo" which is Java Maven project then do update in one of source files and push the updated file to the remote repo. So this is what I did.

1. I installed Eclipse IDE and EGit plugin in my local machine.
2. Imported Foo_Master to my local machine successfully.
3. Updated Java source file named "A.java".

My question is I am not sure how to commit the file to the remote repo.

Note: I saw options under Team > Repository (Please refer to a screenshot). I wonder if one of them or both would commit the file.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I realized that I should Commit first to my local repo then choose either Team > Repository > Push to Upstream or Push Branch Foo_Master to push the touched file from local to remote.